# Reactjs styled-components: create a Read/Show More/Less link with content fading

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I’m trying to create something similar to this [CSS Only: Show More w/ Fade](https://codepen.io/ojbravo/pen/YPJpXe)  by Omar Jesus Bravo, using only styled-components in React.
I’m stuck in using  CSS :target selector with CSS general sibling selector (~) in styled-components. As you can see, I have also used transition and linear-gradient CSS properties.

This is the code I tried:

```
render() {

    return (
        <Container>
          <div>
             <SeeMoreLink href="#show">See More</SeeMoreLink>
             <SeeLessLink href="#hide">See Less</SeeLessLink>
             <ShowHidePanel>
               Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.<br/>
             </ShowHidePanel>
             <ShowHideFade></ShowHideFade>
          <div>
        </Container>
    );
}

const SeeMoreLink = styled.a`
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -1em;
    z-index: 100;
    text-align: center;

    color: #fff;
    background: #000;
    border-radius: 1.5em;
    left: 30%;
    padding: 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 40%;

    &:target ~ ${SeeLessLink} {
        display: block;
    }

    &:target ~ ${ShowHidePanel} {
        max-height: 2000px;
    }
    &:target ~ ${ShowHideFade} {
        margin-top: 0;
    }
`;

const SeeLessLink = styled.a`
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -1em;
    z-index: 100;
    text-align: center;

    color: #fff;
    background: #000;
    border-radius: 1.5em;
    left: 30%;
    padding: 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 40%;

    display: none;
`;

const ShowHidePanel = styled.div`
    position: relative;
    margin: 2em auto;
    width: 70%;
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height .3s ease;
`;
const ShowHideFade = styled.div`
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba($bg-color,0) 0%,rgba($bg-color,1) 75%);
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: -100px;
    position: relative;
`;
```

Please help.